# Google home device and dialogflow

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have a agent,  using V1 dialog flow. Integrated with two Google home devices.

One Google home device is in Europe, one in India. Both the devices are configured ccount. The same account is used to deploy the webhook, deploy and dialogflow agent.

The firmware version is identical.

The agent works perfectly on simulator.

Now when talked on Google home:

Google device in India: When started inovkes, there is a certain pin number which is asked, even when pin is mentioned slowly, spaces are not considered in the dialog flow JSON request pin.original is without spaces, say pin is 12345, JSON request is 12345

Google device in Europe: When started inovkes, there is a certain pin number which is asked, even when pin is mentioned slowly, spaces are  considered in the dialog flow JSON request pin.original is  with spaces and gets trimmed.
say pin is 12345 but JSON request is 123,

Not sure why this is happening.

Any help, please?

Adding the dialog flow requests.........

DF JSON Request coming to backend from Google Home Device in India - Working Fine

```
{
  data: {
    'timestamp': '2018-06-15T17:42:38.261Z',
    'id': 'e5acf434-4e03-4c14-b3d9-e8fc98555694',
    'status': {
      'errorType': 'success', 'code': 200
    }
    ,
    'sessionId': '1529084528066',
    'originalRequest': {
      'source': 'google', 'data': {
        'user': {
          'userId': '1529084528066', 'locale': 'en-US'
        }
        ,
        'surface': {
          'capabilities': [{'name': 'actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO'}, {'name': 'actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT'}]
        }
        ,
        'isInSandbox': True, 'inputs': [{
          'arguments': [{
            'name': 'text',
            'rawText': 'my pin is 23456',
            'textValue': 'my pin is 23456'
          }],
          'intent': 'actions.intent.TEXT',
          'rawInputs': [{'inputType': 'VOICE', 'query': 'my pin is 23456'}]
        }], 'conversation': {
          'conversationId': '1529084528066',
          'conversationToken': '["0748bff2-90d8-4941-8f9f-cf59dd3d009c_id_dialog_context","actions_capability_audio_output","actions_capability_media_response_audio","auth_dialog_context","auth_dialog_params_pin","defaultwelcomeintent-followup","google_assistant_input_type_voice"]',
          'type': 'ACTIVE'
        }
      }
      ,
      'version': '2'
    }
    ,
    'lang': 'en-us',
    'result': {
      'speech': '',
      'action': 'DefaultWelcomeIntent.DefaultWelcomeIntent-custom',
      'actionIncomplete': False,
      'parameters': {
        'phone': '1234567890', 'pin': '23456'
      }
      ,
      'fulfillment': {
        'speech': '', 'messages': [{'speech': '', 'type': 0}]
      }
      ,
      'source': 'agent',
      'contexts': [{
        'name': 'google_assistant_input_type_voice',
        'parameters': {
          'phone': '1234567890',
          'pin': '23456',
          'pin.original': '23456',
          'phone.original': '12345 67890'
        },
        'lifespan': 0
      }, {
        'name': 'actions_capability_audio_output',
        'parameters': {
          'phone': '1234567890',
          'pin': '23456',
          'pin.original': '23456',
          'phone.original': '12345 67890'
        },
        'lifespan': 0
      }, {
        'name': 'auth',
        'parameters': {
          'phone': '1234567890',
          'pin': '23456',
          'pin.original': '23456',
          'phone.original': '12345 67890'
        },
        'lifespan': 5
      }, {
        'name': 'defaultwelcomeintent-followup',
        'parameters': {
          'phone': '1234567890',
          'pin': '23456',
          'pin.original': '23456',
          'phone.original': '12345 67890'
        },
        'lifespan': 1
      }, {
        'name': 'actions_capability_media_response_audio',
        'parameters': {
          'phone': '1234567890',
          'pin': '23456',
          'pin.original': '23456',
          'phone.original': '12345 67890'
        },
        'lifespan': 0
      }],
      'resolvedQuery': 'my pin is 23456',
      'score': 1.0,
      'metadata': {
        'matchedParameters': [{
          'prompts': [{'value': 'Please tell us your pin', 'lang': 'en'}],
          'required': True,
          'name': 'pin',
          'value': '$pin',
          'dataType': '@sys.phone-number',
          'isList': False
        }],
        'webhookUsed': 'true',
        'intentId': '0748bff2-90d8-4941-8f9f-cf59dd3d009c',
        'nluResponseTime': 296,
        'intentName': 'auth',
        'webhookForSlotFillingUsed': 'false',
        'isResponseToSlotfilling': False
      }
    }
  }
}
```

DF JSON Request coming to backend from Google Home Device in Europe - See the pin number issue,

```
{
  data: {
    'timestamp': '2018-06-15T13:19:06.014Z',
    'id': 'ca0ebb47-8bf1-478b-9c87-c704e0114cf9',
    'status': {'errorType': 'success', 'code': 200},
    'sessionId': '1529068715507',
    'originalRequest': {
      'source': 'google',
      'data': {
        'user': {'userId': '1529068715507', 'locale': 'en-US'},
        'surface': {'capabilities': [{'name': 'actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT'}, {'name': 'actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO'}]},
        'isInSandbox': True,
        'inputs': [{
          'arguments': [{
            'name': 'text',
            'rawText': 'my pin is 2 3 4 5 6',
            'textValue': 'my pin is 2 3 4 5 6'
          }],
          'intent': 'actions.intent.TEXT',
          'rawInputs': [{'inputType': 'VOICE', 'query': 'my pin is 2 3 4 5 6'}]
        }],
        'conversation': {
          'conversationId': '1529068715507',
          'conversationToken': '["0748bff2-90d8-4941-8f9f-cf59dd3d009c_id_dialog_context","actions_capability_audio_output","actions_capability_media_response_audio","auth_dialog_context","auth_dialog_params_pin","defaultwelcomeintent-followup","google_assistant_input_type_voice"]',
          'type': 'ACTIVE'
        }
      },
      'version': '2'
    },
    'lang': 'en-us',
    'result': {
      'speech': '',
      'action': 'DefaultWelcomeIntent.DefaultWelcomeIntent-custom',
      'actionIncomplete': False,
      'parameters': {'phone': '1234567890', 'pin': '234'},
      'fulfillment': {'speech': '', 'messages': [{'speech': '', 'type': 0}]},
      'source': 'agent',
      'contexts': [{
        'name': 'google_assistant_input_type_voice',
        'parameters': {
          'phone': '1234567890',
          'pin': '234',
          'pin.original': '2 3 4',
          'phone.original': '123-456-7890'
        },
        'lifespan': 0
      }, {
        'name': 'actions_capability_audio_output',
        'parameters': {
          'phone': '1234567890',
          'pin': '234',
          'pin.original': '2 3 4',
          'phone.original': '123-456-7890'
        },
        'lifespan': 0
      }, {
        'name': 'auth',
        'parameters': {
          'phone': '1234567890',
          'pin': '234',
          'pin.original': '2 3 4',
          'phone.original': '123-456-7890'
        },
        'lifespan': 5
      }, {
        'name': 'actions_capability_media_response_audio',
        'parameters': {
          'phone': '1234567890',
          'pin': '234',
          'pin.original': '2 3 4',
          'phone.original': '123-456-7890'
        },
        'lifespan': 0
      }, {
        'name': 'defaultwelcomeintent-followup',
        'parameters': {
          'phone': '1234567890',
          'pin': '234',
          'pin.original': '2 3 4',
          'phone.original': '123-456-7890'
        },
        'lifespan': 1
      }],
      'resolvedQuery': 'my pin is 2 3 4 5 6',
      'score': 1.0,
      'metadata': {
        'matchedParameters': [{
          'prompts': [{
            'value': 'Please tell us your pin',
            'lang': 'en'
          }],
          'required': True,
          'name': 'pin',
          'value': '$pin',
          'dataType': '@sys.phone-number',
          'isList': False
        }],
        'webhookUsed': 'true',
        'intentId': '0748bff2-90d8-4941-8f9f-cf59dd3d009c',
        'nluResponseTime': 356,
        'intentName': 'auth',
        'webhookForSlotFillingUsed': 'false',
        'isResponseToSlotfilling': False
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you get in the whole utterance?

Comment: What are the locales set for each of the devices? What do you get if you ask for "13579"?

Comment: Dialogflow (DF) language is default English. Both the Google home device Language is set to english. Fyi, one Google home device location is in Sweden and other is in India. But settings apart from location, they are identical. I have edited the post provided the DF request which is coming to backend.
 Please check the pin when uttered 23456, in both the requests. Also the phone no. the formatting which is occurring in both the requests.

Comment: The raw text is taken up with spaces and it's complete, but the parameter value is not taken up correctly in the second case, google home device in Europe.

Comment: Dialogflow is not designed to handle PINs, so it's good that the transcription is valid. You may need to do additional logic to identify the parameter from the raw text.

Comment: Ok, if that is the case, then i am wondering how is it able to fetch the "pin" parameter value from the other device for which I have given the SF request as well.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your *locale* is the same, your *location* is different.
I guess, that this influences the interpretation of [`@sys.phone-number`](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/system-entities#contacts).

So if you would use another `dataType` (e.g. [`@sys.number-sequence`](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/system-entities#api_v2_2)), I think it would work.

 You could probably try this by changing your location in the Google Actions Simulator.

 (Training diverse number sequences seems to [improve the results](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/dialogflow/LV8IA8RrLQM/51rpeZAUBQAJ).)